# React Hide Component when Mobile Keyboard open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mobile

I'm wondering if there is a way to hide React components (Ex. Bottom Navigation Bar Component) while the mobile (Andriod, iOS, etc. ) Keyboard is open on the screen.

Currently I'm doing it with a:

```
@media (max-height: 400px) {
    .navclass {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but am wondering if there is a JS Event or similar.

Answer (score 1):

When am input element is focused on devices of inbuilt keyboards, the keyboards pops up.
ReactJS allows you to write Normal JavaScript in your code.so what you can do is to

```
this.state = {
    isNavVisible: true
}
```

You can now pass this dynamically as a prop on the components and set it to the style of the wrappers element as an inline style in the components main file.

You can then write a function on your inputs or elements that takes focus:

```
const disableNav = () => {
    if(windows.innerWidth <= 400){
          this.setState({isNavVisible: false})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this hook:

```
/**
 * Finds the device name, type, and operating system using navigator. 
 * Any values not found will be undefined.
 * NOTE: This data can be spoofed by the user
 */
export const getDeviceInfo = (): {
    deviceName: string | undefined,
    deviceType: DeviceType | undefined,
    deviceOS: DeviceOS | undefined,
    isMobile: boolean,
    isStandalone: boolean,
} => {
    // Get the user agent string
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    // Determine name
    // Use a regular expression to extract the device name from the user agent string
    const deviceNameRegex = /\((.+?)\)/;
    const deviceNameMatch = userAgent.match(deviceNameRegex);
    const deviceName = deviceNameMatch ? deviceNameMatch[1] : undefined;
    // Determine type
    const isMobile = /Mobile|Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(userAgent);
    const deviceType = isMobile ? DeviceType.Mobile : DeviceType.Desktop;
    // Determine OS
    const isAndroid = /Android/i.test(userAgent);
    const isIOS = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(userAgent);
    const isWindows = /IEMobile|Windows Phone/i.test(userAgent);
    const isMacOS = /Macintosh/i.test(userAgent);
    const isLinux = /Linux/i.test(userAgent);
    const deviceOS = isAndroid ? DeviceOS.Android : isIOS ? DeviceOS.IOS : isWindows ? DeviceOS.Windows : isMacOS ? DeviceOS.MacOS : isLinux ? DeviceOS.Linux : DeviceOS.Unknown;
    // Check if the app is running in standalone mode (i.e. downloaded to the home screen
    const isStandalone = window.matchMedia("(display-mode: standalone)").matches;
    return { deviceName, deviceType, deviceOS, isMobile, isStandalone };
};

/**
 * Hook to detect if the keyboard is open or not. 
 * Useful for hiding fixed elements (e.g. BottomNav).
 */
export const useKeyboardOpen = (): boolean => {
    const [isKeyboardOpen, setIsKeyboardOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Function to handle focus event
        const handleFocus = (event: FocusEvent) => {
            const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
            const isTextBox = target?.role === "textbox" || target?.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
            setIsKeyboardOpen(isTextBox && getDeviceInfo().isMobile);
        };

        // Function to handle blur event
        const handleBlur = () => {
            setIsKeyboardOpen(false);
        };

        // Add event listeners
        window.addEventListener("focusin", handleFocus);
        window.addEventListener("focusout", handleBlur);

        // Cleanup
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("focusin", handleFocus);
            window.removeEventListener("focusout", handleBlur);
        };
    }, []);

    // Check initial state
    useEffect(() => {
        const activeElement = document.activeElement as HTMLElement | null;
        if (!activeElement) return;
        const isTextBox = activeElement?.role === "textbox" || activeElement?.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
        setIsKeyboardOpen(isTextBox && getDeviceInfo().isMobile);
    }, []);

    return isKeyboardOpen;
};
```

All this does is listen for focus events, and decides that the keyboard is open if:

1. The focus event is for a text area, and
2. the userAgent indicates that we're on mobile.